# js function not running on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I apologize for this rather BASIC question, but I am at whits end here!

I have a javascript function that I want to run when the page loads... simple right? I have tried putting the function in doc readys, window readys, putting it before and after the main function, etc etc.  NOTHING seems to work.

Code so far:

```
function calcme() {         
    DA FUNCTON
    }

$(document).ready(function(){   
    calcme();
    $("input").bind("keyup", calcme);

});
```

Please note... the keyup bind DOES work, but I need the calcme function to load on page load. Thoughts?

***UPDATE: As per request, here is the full fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/vpsSA/***

Comment: If the bind works then the initial calcme *must* be called. It may *seem* it is not, but that's due to the behaviour of the function itself (in which we have no insight).

Comment: If `keyup` is working means `onload` function already worked and binded event. Use Firebug to see js error, post `calcme()` method too. It seems it is causing to the error.

Comment: what is ´DA FUNCTON´?. This should work perfectly, you have to check for any problem in the "calcme"

Comment: Did you check for javascript errors when calcme runs?  Did you set a breakpoint in calcme to what it execute and see what's going wrong?

Comment: Have you uploaded this anywhere? Is there a URL?

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions, I have created a js fiddle in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem found**: The `calcme()` function assumes it is called from the context of one of the inputs and uses this.value inside. So, when you call it without any arguments, it obviously fails. This can be solved by trigger the `keyup` of each of your inputs, instead of calling `calcme()` directly. See the fiddle below.

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/vpsSA/1/

---

In your `ready()` handler, the bind statement comes after the `caclme()` call. And as you mentioned the event binding worked. This means:

a) `calcme()` was definitely executed on load. There is no other way since you've mentioned that the binding statement which comes after the `calcme()` call worked as expected.

b) `calcme()` did not throw any JS errors - if so, it would have stopped at the error and the event binding would not have taken place. Maybe it threw a warning, which you'll be able to see in your JS console.

c) Since you haven't provided whats inside `calcme()`, we can't say for sure. But what it looks like is some sort of condition failure because of which you did not get the expected result from `calcme()` when running on load. Are you using anything inside `calcme()` thats initialized *after* running it on load. I would suggest putting in a `debugger;` statement as the first line in your `ready()` handler and tracing it in Firebug or Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I at least understand a bit better now.  Here is the full fiddle if it does shed any light on anything... http://jsfiddle.net/vpsSA/

Comment: OK, problem found. Your `calcme()` function assumes it is called from the context of one of the inputs and uses `this.value` inside. So, when you call it without any arguments, it obviously fails.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense! Thank you! So the code you added loops through each input and "keysup"? Forcing it to run, rather than calling the function?

Comment: Exactly. It simulates a `keyup` on each of your inputs, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function calcme() {         
   try {
      //your code
   }
   catch(e) {
      alert('error: ' + e);
   } 
}

if (typeof $ === undefined)) {
   alert('not jquery');
}

$(document).ready(function(){   

    if (typeof calcme === undefined) {
       alert('calcme not exist');
    }
    else {
       calcme();
       $("input").bind("keyup", calcme);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is unlikely that `calcme()` threw an exception since in that case the statement after that (event binding) wouldn't have got executed.